# Can Production Push notifications be solved without resubmitting app?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Basically, I'm having a PEM certificate issue on my back-end right now, which means my Push Notifications aren't working for production. I'm thinking of going through the process again in my developer.apple.com portal. Would I be able to fix it by redoing the process in there and just toying there and with my server code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if your app is correctly handling notifications and your issue is in your server you can solve it without re-submit the app.

The only issue is testing will push notifications to all the users when you put this to work so be carefull.